# get images from webservice

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am getting images from webservices for particular product.
in the detail view there are 1 or less than 4 images of products.. it's variant.
the images url like

http:/xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx/images/3fbc/prodotti/big/576_1.jpg
http:/xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx/images/3fbc/prodotti/big/576_2.jpg
http:/xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx/images/3fbc/prodotti/big/576_3.jpg
http:/xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx/images/3fbc/prodotti/big/576_4.jpg

576 is a product id.
how can i check that the product have number of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reiterating and checking to see if you get 404's... or have the webservice report this to you somehow.

Comment: this is not the problem i get the images very well, i want to check how many images are on server side for particular product. in the webservice, client didn't show the number of images

Comment: Then you have to keep checking URLs until you find an invalid one, just as @Johan said.

Comment: can you give me an example am try but i don't know how to check url existences??

Comment: this is exactly my code to display image  mainImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
 mainImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 25, 320, 340);
 mainImage.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 NSString *tempImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxx.xxxxx.xx/images/3fbc/prodotti/big/%@_1.jpg",photo];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempImage];
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
 mainImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 [self.view addSubview:mainImage];

Comment: You might want to take a look at my Image Cache project: https://github.com/Koolistov/Image-Cache

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues: memory leaks, unnecessary autorelease pool, invalid URL (missing http bit), synchronous download (blocking UI whilst loading).